# SQL join two tables with a link table between - GORM/Grails

Tags: sql, grails, join

I am trying to build an output as such:

```
Name source source source
Tim  Other  TV      Radio
```

Where I want to combine a Person table and a Source table:

```
Person
ID Name
1  Tim

Source
ID Name
1  Other
2  TV
3  Radio

Person_Source
p_id  s_id
 1     1
 1     2
```

I have a query that builds out each source for time and outputs in multiple lines. I'm looking for a single result in the result set

```
select source.name
from person left join person_source
on person_source.person_source_id = person.id join source
on source.id = person_source.source_id
```

Comment: Why does your desired output show "Radio"?  Doesn't seem that PERSON_SOURCE has a corresponding record in your sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a DISTINCT to your query:

```
select DISTINCT source.name
from person left join person_source
on person_source.person_source_id = person.id join source
on source.id = person_source.source_id
```

Comment: This gave me the ability to use my result set and handle data. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what flavour of SQL this is supposed to be but you could try the following:

```
SELECT
  p.Name,
  MAX(CASE s.ID WHEN 1 THEN s.Name END) AS source1,
  MAX(CASE s.ID WHEN 2 THEN s.Name END) AS source2,
  MAX(CASE s.ID WHEN 3 THEN s.Name END) AS source3
FROM Person p
  INNER JOIN Person_Source ps ON p.ID = ps.p_id
  INNER JOIN Source s ON ps.s_id = s.ID
GROUP BY
  p.ID,
  p.Name
```

You could also check the sources differently, using their names, like this:

```
…
  MAX(CASE s.Name WHEN 'TV'    THEN s.Name END) AS source1,
  MAX(CASE s.Name WHEN 'Radio' THEN s.Name END) AS source2,
  MAX(CASE s.Name WHEN 'Other' THEN s.Name END) AS source3
…
```

Note that a SQL query always return a fixed number of columns. You'll need to decide beforehand how many sources should be returned by the query, and if the number should depend on the actual number of possible sources in the `Source` table, you'll have to build your query dynamically, to include all the necessary sources but no more than necessary.